# Problema al exportar un array

Tags: python, array, csv

Muchachos, tengo un problema al exportar un arreglo numpy 759 x 759. En consola me aparece que aparentemente está completo

Código:

> ```
> import pandas as pd 
> import numpy as np
> df = pd.DataFrame(res)
> A = df.reindex(sorted(df))
>
> array = A.values
> nuevo = array.T
> print(nuevo)
> ```

```
> np.savetxt("distanciafinal.csv", nuevo, delimiter = ",", fmt="%.f")
```

Lo que se imprime por pantalla

[image: Consola]

Sin embargo cuando abro el archivo exportado sólo me muestra información hasta cierta parte, no completa. Cuando en la consola aparece que sí

[image: Excel]

No sé si sea un problema de código en donde estoy exportando mal

Comment: No has puesto el código en el que lo exportas. ¿Cómo lo haces?

Comment: Hola abulafia jaja. Cierto, ya lo pongo

Comment: Listo @abulafia

Comment: Yo usaría pandas para la exportación. Es mucho más rápido y quizás no te dé ese problema. Sería simplemente `A.T.to_csv("fichero.csv")`

Comment: Pero recuerdas que debía hacer la transpuesta en numpy para obtener la matriz deseada? Igual ya ensayo esa opción. Gracias

Comment: Sí, por eso puse `A.T` en vez de `A`. Pandas también sabe hacer transpuestas de dataframes (con la misma sintaxis).

Comment: Intentaste inspeccionando el csv con algún Visualizador de Texto como Notepad? Quizas sirva para encontrar errores. Tambien puedes intentar re-importar el csv con `read_csv` de `pandas`, para inspeccionar el contenido.

Comment: @abulafia Casi perfecto, me arroja todos los resultados pero se cambia el orden en las últimas 10 filas, muy raro, tipo: 757, 758,759,24,56,10..

Comment: @Vichoko no conocía Notepad, ya intento. Gracias

Comment: Bueno, las últimas filas tampoco parecen estar en un orden muy normal en la captura de pantalla que has adjuntado. Quizás hay algo mal en el parámetro `res` con el que construyes el dataframe. ¿No le faltarán claves? Y ¿para qué haces el `reindex` o el `sorted()`? Todo eso me "huele mal"...

Comment: El reindex lo hice porque las filas no me quedaron organizadas.

Answer (score 1):

En teoría lo estás haciendo bien!

Como dice @andres puedes pasarlo a Pandas y exportarlo fácilmente

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(nuevo).to_cvs('distanciafinal.csv')
```

Tambien puedes hacer la transpuesta de un dataframe igual que en Numpy en Pandas

```
pd.DataFrame(array).T.to_csv('distanciafinal.csv')
```

Esto se debe al polimorfismo que hay entre Numpy y Pandas, ya que Pandas está construido sobre Numpy y por tanto "piensa" en arrays de Numpy, por lo que hay muchas funciones iguales y se compenetran muy bien entre sí las dos librerías.